# Splitting a string into words in a culture neutral way

Tags: c#, full-text-search

I've come up with the method below that aims to split a text of variable length into an array of words for further full text index processing (stop word removal, followed by stemmer). The results seem to be ok but I would like to hear opinions how reliable this implementation would against texts in different languages. Would you recommend using a regex for this instead? Please note that I've opted against using String.Split() because that would require me to pass a list of all known seperators which is exactly what I was trying to avoid when I wrote the function

P.S: I can't use a full blown full text search engine like Lucene.Net for several reasons (Silverlight, Overkill for project scope etc).

```
public string[] SplitWords(string Text)
{
    bool inWord = !Char.IsSeparator(Text[0]) && !Char.IsControl(Text[0]);
    var result = new List<string>();
    var sbWord = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
    {
        Char c = Text[i];

        // non separator char?
        if(!Char.IsSeparator(c) && !Char.IsControl(c))
        {
            if (!inWord)
            {
                sbWord = new StringBuilder();
                inWord = true;
            }

            if (!Char.IsPunctuation(c) && !Char.IsSymbol(c))
                sbWord.Append(c);
        }

        // it is a separator or control char
        else
        {
            if (inWord)
            {
                string word = sbWord.ToString();
                if (word.Length > 0)
                    result.Add(word);

                sbWord.Clear();
                inWord = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said in culture neutral way, I really doubt if Regular Expression (word boundary: \b) will do. I have googled a bit and found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/breaker.aspx). Hope it would be useful.
I am pretty surprised that there is no built-in Java [BreakIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) equivalent...

Comment: The link was quite helpful. Thanks!