# C# - Fastest way to find one of a set of strings in another string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I need to check whether a string contains any swear words.

Following some advice from another question here, I made a HashSet containing the words:

```
HashSet<string> swearWords = new HashSet<string>() { "word_one", "word_two", "etc" };
```

Now I need to see if any of the values contained in `swearWords` are in my string.

I've seen it done the other way round, eg:

```
swearWords.Contains(myString)
```

But this will return false.

What's the fastest way to check if any of the words in the HashSet are in `myString`?

NB: I figure I can use a foreach loop to check each word in turn, and break if a match is found, I'm just wondering if there's a faster way.

Comment: Why are you using a `HashSet`? Might be easier to use `List<String>` here. And then split `myString` into a list and do the necessary comparison.

Comment: @SkonJeet: if the list of swear words is large, checking for containment will be faster for a `HashSet` than a `List` - and I can't see that a `List` would make it any *easier*.

Comment: I was originally using a list and then converted it to a HashSet as I read they are faster to check values in

Comment: @SkonJeet: A `HashSet` has different performance characteristics (and it does not allow dupes).

Comment: NB: There are around 50 swear words in the list so it's fairly large

Comment: Is something wrong with the world today? JonSkeet and SkonJeet... I can't take this seriously.

Comment: @JonSkeet - ahh right, glad I've learnt that. Apologies for providing poor information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try a regex, but I'm not sure it's faster.

```
Regex rx = new Regex("(" + string.Join("|", swearWords) + ")");
rx.IsMatch(myString)
```

Comment: +1 - Swear words are best described as regular expressions. I'm talking from my experience. However, it is practically impossible to beat users with a static algorithm and a word list.

Answer (score 10):

If you place your swears in an IEnumerable<> implementing container:

```
var containsSwears = swarWords.Any(w => myString.Contains(w));
```

Note: HashSet<> implements IEnumerable<>

Comment: `HashSet<T>` does implement `IEnumerable<T>`. (And you need to watch out for the Scunthorpe problem if you're using this approach: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)

Comment: @LukeH: good point but beyond the scope of this discussion. Perhaps better as a comment on the question. +1

Comment: lol@scunthorpe, nice name. However if your logic for breaking the words down works you should be clear of that problem because you are checking entire words, not strings within words. A problem you might have is matching case-sensitivity of the words or words that use leet speak.

Comment: @Adam: That's why I made the comments against this particular answer -- it's recommending [`string.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) so will be susceptible to the problem.

Comment: Caveat: I'll admit this is an overly simple answer but leave it to others to suggest as I don't have much knowledge in this specific domain.

Comment: The scunthorpe problem isn't a huge issue to this, as it's to do with choosing some content to display on a home page. If it contains swearing, it doesn't make the home page 'trending' list. Therefore false positives aren't that much of a problem.

Comment: The answer here is great, but I can't use linq unfortunately as it's not .NET 4 :(

Comment: @surfitscrollit: LINQ became available with .NET3.5, so if you're able to use `HashSet<T>` then you can almost certainly use LINQ too.

Comment: @LukeH whoops, didn't realise!

Comment: Understanding that you CAN use LINQ, .Any() is just a fancy foreach (with the foreach effectively hidden inside the enumerator.)

Answer (score 7):

If you have really large set of swear words you could use Aho–Corasick algorithm: http://tomasp.net/blog/ahocorasick.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with such schemes is *defining what a word is in the context of the string you want to check*.

- Naive implementations such as those using `input.Contains` simply do not have the concept of a word; they will "detect" swear words even when that was not the intent.
- Breaking words on whitespace is not going to cut it (consider also punctuation marks, etc).
- Breaking on characters other than whitespace is going to raise culture issues: what characters are considered word-characters exactly?

Assuming that your stopword list only uses the latin alphabet, a practical choice would be to assume that words are sequences consisting of only latin characters. So a reasonable starting solution would be

```
var words = Regex.Split(@"[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]", myString);
```

The regex above is the standard class `\W` modified to not include digits; for more info, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx. For other approaches, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687357/splitting-a-string-into-words-in-a-culture-neutral-way) and possibly the CodeProject link supplied in the accepted answer.

Having split the input string, you can iterate over `words` and replace those that match anything in your list (use `swearWords.Contains(word)` to check) or simply detect if there are any matches at all with

```
var anySwearWords = words.Intersect(swearWords).Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could split "myString" into an IEnumerable type, and then use "Overlaps" on them?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355623(v=vs.90).aspx

(P.S. Long time no see...)

**EDIT**: Just noticed error in my previous answer.

Comment: In fact, I've just double checked, Overlaps looks like it would pretty much do exactly what you need? Not sure on efficiency though.